# In Azure file copy, can you do a copy into the root container?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

My Azure file copy properties within Azure Dev Ops are as follows:

Source:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactName/Folder

Destination Type:
Azure Blob

Container Name:
container

Blob Prefix:
[Blank]

When I go ahead and execute the task, the files within the source folder are successfully copied to:

container/folder/[files]

Where the above path has inherited it's naming from [Container Name] / [Source Folder Name] / [Source File Name]

What I would prefer is for the source folder name to not be inherited and therefore be:

container/[files]

Am I able to achieve this using the Azure file copy task in Azure Dev Ops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify the `source` as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactName/Folder`. It copies a directory (and all of the files in that directory) to a blob container. The result is a directory in the container by the same name. ie. `container/folder/[files]`

If you want only the files be copied in the root container. You can specify the `source` by using the wildcard symbol (*), like this `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactName/Folder/*`. It will upload the contents of a directory without copying the containing directory. ie. `container/[files]` See below:

`Source: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactName/Folder/*`

See [azcopy document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#upload-a-directory) for more information.